# Laravel 5.8 session confusion from simultaneous authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session, server

I've got 3 projects on Laravel 5.8 right now and they all have the same problem.

When I try to login from 2 or more different browsers on the same user account, if it is done with a 0.5 seconds semi-perfect sync, it mixes up all the php/laravel sessions. So some users are logged with the correct username, and some are logged with the username and the session ID of others. Everything is scrambled.

I am 100% sure that it comes from the session, because all the logged browser have the same session ID if we dump it in the home page after the post-login redirection.

Even if the test is done with different IPs, the same problem occurs. 2 login attempts from 2 different IPs on 2 different PCs get the same problem if the log is done in the same time. They get the same session ID, the same logged user and everything.

On Laravel, I tried different drivers for the session : MYSQL, file and cookies. And we ALWAYS get the same problem.

I tried with php 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3 and the problem stays on each PHP versions.

Comment: Solved the problem: The problem was coming from Apache. I installed my web application on a Nginx server and it solved the problem.